# Gerrit’s internal shell can’t find git-receive-pack after upgrading to 2.13.4 from 2.9

Tags: git, ssh, gerrit

We recently upgraded our Gerrit server from 2.9 to 2.13.4. We got everything working except access to the repositories over SSH, which uses Gerrit’s internal SSH server that is implemented in Java with jgit. Gerrit’s internal shell can’t find git-receive-pack. All of the other normal Gerrit SSH commands appear to be working, and HTTPS access to all the repositories are working fine.

In particular, this is what I expect from `git --help`:

```
$ ssh -p 29418 me@robotics.our-machine.net git --help
git [COMMAND] [ARG ...] [--] [--help (-h)]

 --          : end of options
 --help (-h) : display this help text

Available commands of git are:

   receive-pack
   upload-pack

See 'git COMMAND --help' for more information.
```

This is what it looks like instead:

```
$ ssh -p 29418 me@robotics.our-machine.net git --help
git [COMMAND] [ARG ...] [--] [--help (-h)]

 --          : end of options
 --help (-h) : display this help text

Available commands of git are:


See 'git COMMAND --help' for more information.
```

This is what happens when I try fetching from an existing repository, which used to work with version 2.9:

```
$ git fetch gerrit
fatal: Gerrit Code Review: git-upload-pack: not found
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Does anybody have any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: What which git-upload-pack returns on the Gerrit machine ?

Comment: `michael@robotics:~$ which git-upload-pack` returns 
`/usr/bin/git-upload-pack`

Answer (score 0):

One of our team members figured out that we needed to add the following lines to the `[download]` section of the `gerrit/review_site/etc/gerrit.config` file:

```
   command = checkout
   command = cherry_pick
   command = pull
   scheme = ssh
```

and restart gerrit.  In case it helps someone, here are all of the line in the `[download]` section:

```
[download]
        command = checkout
        command = cherry_pick
        command = pull
        scheme = http
        scheme = ssh
        archive = tbz2
        archive = tgz
```

The `git --help` output now shows the `upload-archive` and `upload-pack` commands as being available.  I suspect that had we installed a new copy of gerrit rathern than going through the upgrades that these configuration options would have been set for us already.

```
# ssh -p 29418 michael@robotics.our-machine.net git --help
git [COMMAND] [ARG ...] [--] [--help (-h)]

 --          : end of options
 --help (-h) : display this help text

Available commands of git are:

   receive-pack     
   upload-archive   
   upload-pack
```